# NSCollectionView: Can the same object not be in the array more than once or is this a bug?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

I may be doing this all wrong, but I thought I was on the right track until I hit this little snag. Basically I was putting together a toy using NSCollectionView and trying to understand how to hook that all up using IB. I have a button which will add a couple of strings to the NSArrayController:

[image]

The first time I press this button, my strings appear in the collection view as expected:

[image]

The second time I press the button, the views scroll down and room is made - but the items don't appear to get added. I just see blank space:

[image]

The button is implemented as follows (controller is a pointer to the NSArrayController I added in IB):

```
- (IBAction)addStuff:(id)control
{
    [controller addObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"String 1",@"String 2",@"String 3",nil]];
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Rather than try to explain all the connections/binds/etc, if you need more info, I'd be grateful if you could just take a quick look at the [toy project](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/545670/Toy.zip) itself.

**UPDATE:** After more experimentation as suggested by James Williams, it seems the problem stems from having multiple objects with the same memory address in the array. This confuses either NSArrayController or NSCollectionView (not sure which). Changing my addStuff: to this resulted in the behavior I originally expected:

```
[controller addObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"String 1"],[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"String 2"],[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"String 3"],nil]];
```

So the question now, I guess, is if this is a bug I should report to Apple or if this is intended/documented behavior and I just missed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning the exact same immutable string to the address is by design. It is a performance optimization.

A different way to accomplish your goal would be:

```
NSString* param1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"string1"];
NSString* param2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"string2"];
NSString* param3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"string3"];

[controller addObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:param1,param2,param3,nil]];

[param1 release];
[param2 release];
[param3 release];
```

edit:
Just using the stringWithFormat is sufficent it turns out

```
[controller addObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"string1"],
                                                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"string2"],
                                                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"string3"],nil]];
```

Answer (score 2):

[Edit: doing some playing around and it definitely seems to be a "duplicate item" issue. You might want to re-title this question so you can get some better answers. It's really weird. I'd like to know the answer myself.]

Things work a bit better with this:

```
if([[controller arrangedObjects] count] == 0)
   [controller addObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"String 1",@"String 2",@"String 3",nil]];
else 
   [controller addObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"String 4", @"String 5", @"String 6", nil]];
```

which leads me to believe that it has something to do with @"String 1", etc. being the same object twice in the array. I would have expected that to work.

So I'm not too clear on what's going on. But a work-around is to not put identical things in there. Not a very good work-around, huh?

I would have expected

```
[controller addObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"String 1"],
                            [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"String 2"],
                            [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"String 3"],
                            nil]];
```

to work. But it doesn't. Which also confuses me. NSCollectionView is very strange sometimes.

Comment: I had a similar thought before I submitted this to SO and tried [@"String 1" copy] to see what would happen. That didn't make any difference either, but likely Cocoa is doing something special with static strings that might cause them to always have the same address since they are truly immutable (I didn't test that yet, though). This does seem like a strange limitation and I wonder if it's NSCollectionView or the NSArrayController that's really at fault.

Comment: Yep. It's got to be the duplicate objects thing. (Specifically, object instances with the same address.) I decided to try forcing it to create new strings every time and the easiest way I could think of was to turn the static strings into NSMutableStrings. That made it work. (The question now is, is this a bug or by design?) Like so: [controller addObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"String 1"],[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"String 2"],[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"String 3"],nil]];

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call this type of limitation a bug. A data driven view typically expects to use the content objects as keys. For example, in NSOutlineView you have these two methods:

```
– itemAtRow:
– rowForItem:
```

Where item is some arbitrary object either supplied via bindings, or through the data source mechanism. If the objects in the outline view aren't unique, how is NSOutlineView supposed to reliably implement rowForItem:? If the same object appeared N times in the outline view, there would be N rows for it.

NSCollectionView doesn't seem to have an interface that precludes multiple instances of the same content object, but I think this expectation is typical of data driven views.

You should use unique content objects.